# Ubuntu 18.04 imagemagick does not contain imagemagick binaries

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, imagemagick

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I needed to use imagemagick, a useful tool when needed, but one I rarely use, but I could not find it using `imagemagick`, or `which imagemagick` so I ran `sudo dpkg-query -L imagemagick` and the result showed only document files installed and also checked `apt search imagemagick` to ensure imagemagick was installed and nothing appeared to be missing which shows both imagemagick and imagemagick-6-common installed.

```
sudo dpkg-query -L imagemagick
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/copyright
/usr/share/bug/imagemagick
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/changelog.Debian.gz

apt search imagemagick
imagemagick/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3 amd64 [installed]
image manipulation programs -- binaries

imagemagick-6-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security,now 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3 all [installed,automatic]
image manipulation programs -- infrastructure
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure imagemagick 6 doesn't have a command named `imagemagick`. https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php

Comment: But as shown in the post the listed files from imagemagick apt package are only doc files, but the apt search says binaries

Comment: The actual binaries are provided by two other packages: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/imagemagick This package exists so that graphicsmagick can "provide" imagemagick commands. Installing it will get you the commands, one way or the other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imagemagick works for me in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Please notice, that it is the name of the program package to be installed, but the programs to be executed have other names, for example `convert`, `mogrify`, `display`.

See `man convert`, `man mogrify`, `man display`, and some tutorial about Imagemagick, for example

[Examples of ImageMagick Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot to run `sudo dpkg-query -L imagemagick-6-common` which has all. Don't know why `apt search imagemagick` says binaries for imagemagic package though.

Comment: @SudoSURoot, You are welcome :-)